# 2D Array Memory Allocation (malloc) Returns NULL

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, malloc

I am trying to compile a **64-bit CPP code** using **GCC**, however multidimensional (i.e. 2D) array memory allocation returns `NULL` once I increase the element size from **46,000** to **46,500**. My virtual memory is set to 96GB, and hardware is running 64-bit OS using 32GB Ram. **The code works fine as long as** `MAX_VERTICES` **does not exceed** `46000`.

Following is what I am trying to dynamically allocate:

```
struct ShortestPath {
    real32 totalWeight;
    // NOTE: ShortestPath is a list of pointers; does not make copies 
    // (i.e. side-effects) the pointers point to memory allocated
    // in the DijkstraSPTree array in the vehicle_searching module
    List<DirectedEdge *> *edgeList;
};

#define MAX_VERTICES 46500
global_variable ShortestPath spAllPairs[MAX_VERTICES][MAX_VERTICES];
```

---

Allocate Memory on the Heap to replace

```
spAllPairs[MAX_VERTICES][MAX_VERTICES]
```

with the following code

```
global_variable ShortestPath **spAllPairs;
global_variable ShortestPath *arr_data;

ShortestPath *getShortestPath(EdgeWeightedDigraph *digraph, int32 source,
                              int32 dest)
{
    free(spAllPairs); // Function is called multiple times so I clear memory
    free(arr_data); // before reallocation given values pointed by pointers
    free(spTreesArray); // are used in other files in my project after run.

    inline allocate_mem(ShortestPath*** arr, ShortestPath** arr_data, int n, int m);
    allocate_mem(&spAllPairs, &arr_data, MAX_VERTICES, MAX_VERTICES);
    for (unsigned int k = 0 ; k < MAX_VERTICES ; k++) {
        if (spAllPairs[k] == NULL) {
            while (k >= 1) {
                free(spAllPairs[k]);
                --k;
            }
            free(spAllPairs[0]);
            free(spAllPairs);
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate space for Shortest Path Pairs!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    spTreesArray = (DijkstraSPTree *)malloc(MAX_VERTICES * sizeof(DijkstraSPTree));
    for (int32 vertexTo = 0; vertexTo < digraph->vertices; ++vertexTo) {
        pathTo(&spTreesArray[source], &spAllPairs[source][vertexTo],
                   vertexTo);
    }
    return &spAllPairs[source][dest];
}

void pathTo(DijkstraSPTree *spTree, ShortestPath *shortestPath, int32 dest)
{
    List<DirectedEdge *>::traverseList(freeDirectedEdge, shortestPath->edgeList);
    List<DirectedEdge *>::emptyList(&shortestPath->edgeList);
    shortestPath->totalWeight = spTree->distTo[dest];
}

int allocate_mem(ShortestPath ***arr, ShortestPath **arr_data, int n, int m)
{
    *arr = (ShortestPath **)malloc(n * sizeof(ShortestPath*));
    *arr_data = (ShortestPath *)malloc(n * m * sizeof(ShortestPath));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        (*arr)[i] = *arr_data + i * m;
    return 0; //free point
}
```

Comment: Remember that allocations on the heap has to be *contiguous*. You try to allocate 32 gigs of memory (if `sizeof(ShortestPath) == 16` which most likely is) as one big chunk. If there's no such large contiguous chunk of memory, the allocation will fail.

Comment: `46000 x 46000` is below 1.97 Gigs, whereas `46500 x 46500` is 2.013 Gigs. If the size of your struct is 16, than `46000` might remain below 32 GB, whereas 46500 yields more than 32GB. Check results of your `mallocs`, they should get NULL at some point

Comment: @StephanLechner Physical memory shouldn't matter since I am using malloc, and virtual memory is 96GB. I am not sure if it is contiguous though. I get NULL at 46500x46500 during initialization of "spAllPairs".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, the size of ShortestPath = 16 as you indicated. What am I supposed to do in this situation? Would restarting my PC or increasing the size of Virtual Memory help? Thanks

Comment: Operating system *may* provide virtual memory as well (when requested through malloc), but I cannot say if it *actually does* in your system. Anyway, if 46000 works and 46500 not, it is at least noteable that this is probably the 32GB margin. If `malloc` returns `NULL`, it could not allocate the desired block.

Comment: "My virtual memory is set to 96GB, and hardware is running 64-bit OS using 32GB Ram" Do you like thrashing? That's how you get thrashing.

Comment: Make multiple smaller allocations instead of a single big one? E.g. one for each `(*arr)[i]`.

Comment: You also forgot to tell what exactly doesn't work. "malloc failed" is not a useful description of the problem, especially if you never check what it returned anyway. Tell us what you observe.

Comment: Also bear in mind that `malloc` is a dangerous thing to use in C++, as are arrays and pointers. Have you tried and rejected an `std::vector` based solution?

Comment: @n.m. I am compiling C code so can't use std::vector. I certainly prefer vector based approach. Anyway, malloc returns "NULL" once MAX_VERTICES exceeds 46000.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It would not be as efficient and would make it harder for me to keep track of several small blocks as opposed to one big block.

Comment: @Far: this ain't C code: `List<DirectedEdge *> *edgeList;`. removing the [c] tag.

Comment: @chqrlie oh yes, it is C++. I wonder what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

The function `allocate_mem` is inconsistent with the code used in `getShortestPath` to free the structures. If `arr_data` is not used elsewhere, you should remove this global variable and allocate an indirect array this way:

```
ShortestPath **allocate_mem(int n, int m) {
    ShortestPath **arr = (ShortestPath **)calloc(n, sizeof(*arr));
    if (arr != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = (ShortestPath *)calloc(m, sizeof(ShortestPath));
            if (arr[i] == NULL)
                break;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Notes:

- it would be safer to store `NULL` into the global pointers after you `free` the memory they point to.
- it would be more consistent for `allocate_mem` to check if it could allocate all the array elements and free whatever was allocated if not, instead of trying to clean up in the caller function.

Here is a more consistent version and the calling code:

```
    ShortestPath **allocate_mem(int n, int m) {
        ShortestPath **arr = (ShortestPath **)calloc(n, sizeof(*arr));
        if (arr != NULL) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                arr[i] = (ShortestPath *)calloc(m, sizeof(ShortestPath));
                if (arr[i] == NULL) {
                    for (j = i; j-- > 0;) {
                        free(arr[j]);
                    }
                    free(arr);
                    return NULL;
                }
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }

    ShortestPath *getShortestPath(EdgeWeightedDigraph *digraph, int32 source,
                                  int32 dest)
    {
        // Function is called multiple times so I clear memory
        // before reallocation given values pointed by pointers
        // are used in other files in my project after run.
        free(spAllPairs);
        spAllPairs = NULL;
        free(arr_data);
        arr_data = NULL;
        free(spTreesArray);
        spTreesArray = NULL;

        spAllPairs = allocate_mem(MAX_VERTICES, MAX_VERTICES);
        if (spAllPairs == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate space for Shortest Path Pairs!\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        spTreesArray = (DijkstraSPTree *)malloc(MAX_VERTICES * sizeof(DijkstraSPTree));
        if (spTreesArray == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate space for DijkstraSPTree!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        for (int32 vertexTo = 0; vertexTo < digraph->vertices; ++vertexTo) {
            pathTo(&spTreesArray[source], &spAllPairs[source][vertexTo],
                   vertexTo);
        }
        return &spAllPairs[source][dest];
    }
```

**EDIT** as **M.M** commented, you should use the `new` and `delete` operators in C++ instead of `malloc()` and `free()`. (or in addition to `malloc`, but why bother with `malloc` anyway):

```
ShortestPath **allocate_mem(int n, int m) {
    ShortestPath **arr = new ShortestPath *[n];
    if (arr != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = new ShortestPath[m];
            if (arr[i] == NULL) {
                for (j = i; j-- > 0;) {
                    delete[] arr[j];
                }
                delete[] arr;
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

ShortestPath *getShortestPath(EdgeWeightedDigraph *digraph, int32 source,
                              int32 dest)
{
    // Function is called multiple times so I clear memory
    // before reallocation given values pointed by pointers
    // are used in other files in my project after run.
    delete[] spAllPairs;
    spAllPairs = NULL;
    delete[] spTreesArray;
    spTreesArray = NULL;

    spAllPairs = allocate_mem(MAX_VERTICES, MAX_VERTICES);
    if (spAllPairs == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate space for Shortest Path Pairs!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    spTreesArray = new DijkstraSPTree *[MAX_VERTICES];
    if (spTreesArray == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate space for DijkstraSPTree!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int32 vertexTo = 0; vertexTo < digraph->vertices; ++vertexTo) {
        pathTo(&spTreesArray[source], &spAllPairs[source][vertexTo],
               vertexTo);
    }
    return &spAllPairs[source][dest];
}
```

Comment: It's undefined behaviour to use malloc-family and then write into the space, without also creating objects via placement-new. (So you should use `new` in the first place).

Comment: Error: `(*arr)[i] = new ShortestPath[m];` no match for `operator=` Operand types are `ShortestPath` and `ShortestPath*`

Comment: Just replaced 2d array with 2d vector, and it works like a charm. There is no need to use malloc and further complicate the code.

Comment: @Far: my bad, the tree star programmer caught me after dark.  Answer updated.